# Get Apost From Page on Facebook using php?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Hi I have Joined a facebook Group  and I want to get the recent posts on my website using PHP.

I don't know where to begin. I used google to look this up but all I could find was how to get post from an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you'd want to use Facebook's API: https://developers.facebook.com/. More specifically [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group) is the documentation regarding accessing data from a group.